# Spring 4.1.5 and Tiles 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles

I want to integrate Spring MVC with Apache Tiles, given the version, when I run my webapp it shows a strange error. Please see logs.

```
Apr 13, 2015 8:35:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [tiles] in context with path [/TestMvcTiles] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: XML error reading definitions.] with root cause
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 19; Document root element "tiles-definition", must match DOCTYPE root "tiles-definitions".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:325)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResource(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:150)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:234)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:225)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:225)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:203)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:192)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:68)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:174)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:131)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:105)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:49)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.getDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:286)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.isValidDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:273)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.isRenderable(DefinitionRenderer.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.checkResource(TilesView.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1267)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/ns/javaee/web-app_4_1.xsd"
xmlns:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/ns/javaee/web-app_4_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="4.1">

<display-name>tiles</display-name>
       <servlet>
              <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
              <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
       </servlet>   

       <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

       <listener>
              <listener- class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
       </listener>
       <welcome-file-list>
              <welcome-file>
                     home.htm
              </welcome-file>
       </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**/WEB-INF/tiles-servlet.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd"
> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller"/>
       <mvc:annotation-driven/>       
</beans>
```

**/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd"
> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller"/>
       <context:annotation-config/>
       <mvc:annotation-driven/>  

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView</value>
        </property>        
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
           <list>
                     <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tilesJsp.xml</value>
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**/WEB-INF/tiles/tilesJsp.xml**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd"> 
<tiles-definition>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/view/base.jsp">
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Spring MVC And Tiles"/> 
       <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp"/> 
       <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/view/menu.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
       <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/view/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="baseLayout">
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Home"/>
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="page" extends="baseLayout">
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Page"/>
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/page.jsp"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definition>
```

**/myproj/java resources/src/com/test/controller/HomeController.xml**

```java
package com.test.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home.htm")
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("Home");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/page.htm")
    public String page(@RequestParam(value="pageNo") String pageNo, HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("Page No: "+pageNo);
        request.setAttribute("pageNo", pageNo);
        return "page";
    }
}
```

The  **/WEB-INF/view/** contains the .jsp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace says this:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 19; Document root element "tiles-definition", must match DOCTYPE root "tiles-definitions".
```

You tiles definitions starts like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd"> 
  <tiles-definition>
```

You should be able to fix this error by following the advice in the exception and changing tiles-definition to tiles-definitions.

The documentation confirms this is the correct element name.
https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html

Answer (score 2):

I tried Ben's answer and it still gave me the same error, then I replaced  to  and it worked fine.

Update code:

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd"> 
  <tiles-definitions>
```